# WordPress Static Menu (WordPress 3.8)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am stuck and trying to figure out the Problem... in WordPress site

[al-hussain](http://dotcomsourcing.com/projects/al-hussain/)

now the Problem is that,
i found a menu appearing on the home, i changed my menu..but when i clicked on pages just `#`
was the URL of All Pages but the page `Contact-us` has actual link, and the menu winch i created now appears in actual position..means when i goes to contact-us page and than my created menu is activated else,the `default` or `static` `menu` is appearing... even though i delete all my created menu but on loading site it shows menu...

default Menu is
[image]

and after clicking on contact us the menu is

[image]

here is `header.php` main_nav_menu

```
<!-- Begin main nav -->
            <div id="nav_wrapper">
                <div class="nav_wrapper_inner">
                    <div id="menu_border_wrapper">
                        <?php   
                            if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) 
                            {
                                //Get page nav
                                wp_nav_menu( 
                                        array( 
                                            'menu_id'           => 'main_menu',
                                            'menu_class'        => 'nav',
                                            'theme_location'    => 'primary-menu',
                                        ) 
                                ); 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    echo '<div class="notice">Please setup "Main Menu" using Wordpress Dashboard > Appearance > Menus</div>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

any one can figure out ! please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i sloved the Problem by Deleting the Cache, here i found directory

```
wp-content/cache/supercache/
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your `header.php` file? I believe you have static menu there.

Here is the syntax to create a menu that you have created at the backend

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'main_menu', 'container' => '') ); ?>
```

Replace your static menu with the code above with the name changed in the 'menu' parameter

Comment: Let me see header.php

Comment: Now Please Check header.php

Comment: Zameer Khan i Edited Question

Comment: Try using `menu` parameter. `'menu' => 'your-menu-name'`

Comment: same problem now, there is browser issue, the changings applied on fireFox, But not on Chrome